# como pasar un arreglo de objetos entre javascript y php con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Hola a todos me tope con un problema y no lo e podido resolver ojala puedan ayudarme.

mi problema es el siguiente:
En javascript tengo un arreglo en el cual mediante otras funciones lo lleno de objetos lo cuales constan de 2 datos (id y cantidad).

luego intento pasar este arreglo a php por un ajax para posteriromente en php hacer varias inserciones a una base de datos en mysql la cuestion es que no se que estoy haciendo mal ya que ajax me pasa correctamente los datos pero en php no soy capaz de manejar ese arreglo de objetos que pase.

en cuestion para que entiendan un poco mas en que trabajo en este apartado les explico un poco:
tengo 2 tablas en mi base de datos una que se llama ordenes y otra que se llama detalle(detalle es una tabla puente entre mi tabla de detalle y productos) en esta detallo todos los productos que se compraron en una orden entonces lo que intento hacer es primero insertar en mi tabla de ordenes, posteriormente recupero el ultimo id insertado en la tabla de ordenes ya que lo voy a nesesitar para hacer n inserciones en la tabla de detalle estas las intento hacer con un foreache mediante el arreglo que intento pasa entre javascript y php por ajax.

a continuacion les dejo mi codigo para ver si me pueden ayudar:

```
    function ordenar(){
    var nombre = document.getElementById("nom").value;
    var telefono = document.getElementById("tel").value;
    var ubicacion = document.getElementById("ubi").value;

    if(nombre != "" && telefono != "" && ubicacion != ""){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"abrirPedido.php",
            data:{"nombre":nombre,"telefono":telefono,"ubicacion":ubicacion,"carrito":JSON.stringify(carrito)},
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },error: function(data){
                alert(data['codigo']);
            }
        });
        //window.location.href = "Index.php";

        alert("Su pedido esta en camino, gracias por su preferencia");
    }else{
        alert("Favor de llenar todos los campos");
    }
}
```

esta es mi funcion en java script que me inicializa mi ajax si ven aqui le intento mandar un arreglo transformandolo en un script con la funcion JSON.stringify y otros datos nesesarios que son datos normales.

```
function producto(codigo){
    this.Id = codigo;
    this.cantidad = 1;
}
```

esta es la funcion me ayuda a crear los objetos como una clase

```
function agregar(clave){
    var ban = false;

    if(carrito.length > 0){
        for(i = 0;i < carrito.length;i++){
            if(carrito[i].Id == clave){
                carrito[i].cantidad++;
                ban = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!ban){
            p = new producto(clave);
            carrito.push(p);
        }
    }else{
        p = new producto(clave);
        carrito.push(p);
    }
    cant++;
    document.getElementById("cant").innerHTML = cant;
}
```

esta es otra funcion javascript que uso para introducir mis objetos en el arreglo

```
<?php
    include("conexion.php");
    ini_set('date.timezone','America/Mexico_City');

    $cliente = $_POST['nombre'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $direccion = $_POST['ubicacion'];
    $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
    $productos = json_decode(json_encode($_POST['carrito']),true);

    $query = "insert into Ordenes(Cliente,fecha,direccion,telefono,Id_estatus) values('$cliente','$fecha','$direccion','$telefono',2)";

    mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
    $id_orden = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);

    foreach($productos as $p){
        $id_producto = intval($p->Id);
        $cantidad = intval($p->cantidad);

        $queryPre = "select Precio from Productos where id_producto = $id_producto";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$queryPre);
        $totalUnitario = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);
        $tu = floatval($totalUnitario[0]);

        $queryDet = "insert into detalle values($id_orden,$id_producto,$cantidad,$tu)";
        mysqli_query($conexion,$queryDet);
    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);

    echo json_encode("exito");
?>
```

y por ultimo este es mi codigo php en donde intento hacer una insercio para la tabla de ordenes y una insercion por cada objeto en mi arreglo

Answer (score 0):

Hola compañeros despues de un buen rato buscando encontre el problema algo muy simple pero que estaba interpretando mal en php ya que el arreglo lo mandaba bien javascript pero en php lo estaba interpretando mal les comento el codifo php que me funciono para que si alguien mas se encuenta con este problema le sirva ya que si fue algo simple pero un dolor de cabeza jejejeje

```
<?php
    include("conexion.php");
    ini_set('date.timezone','America/Mexico_City');

    $cliente = $_POST['nombre'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $direccion = $_POST['ubicacion'];
    $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
    $productos = json_decode($_POST['carrito'],true);

    $query = "insert into Ordenes(Cliente,fecha,direccion,telefono,Id_estatus) values('$cliente','$fecha','$direccion','$telefono',2)";

    mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
    $id_orden = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);

    foreach($productos as $p => $d){
        $id_producto = intval($d['Id']);
        $cantidad = intval($d['cantidad']);

        $queryPre = "select Precio from Productos where id_producto = $id_producto";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$queryPre);
        $totalUnitario = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);
        $tu = floatval($totalUnitario[0]);

        $queryDet = "insert into detalle values($id_orden,$id_producto,$cantidad,$tu)";
        mysqli_query($conexion,$queryDet);
    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

podran observar la diferencia en como uso solo json_decode para transformar el arreglo que envio como string en javascript y ajax usando json.stringify() y en mi foreach para recorrer correctamente el arreglo de objetos en php

Espero les sirva de antemano gracias